# Trying to use nodemailer to send emails using gmail and am receiving the error: "Can't create new access token for user"

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, google-oauth

I currently have a setup to send emails using nodemailer from gmail. It works correctly when I manually create an access token (which only last for ~1 hour). However, after that hour has passed I get the below error. Note, during that hour I am able to send emails just fine and everything works.

```
 { Error: Can't create new access token for user
at XOAuth2.generateToken (C:\Users\user\My-Projects\***\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js:162:33)
at XOAuth2.getToken (C:\Users\user\My-Projects\***\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js:111:18)
at SMTPConnection._handleXOauth2Token (C:\Users\user\My-Projects\***\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1421:27)
at Immediate.setImmediate (C:\Users\user\My-Projects\***\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1239:45)
at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5) code: 'EAUTH', command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

The code I am using to send the email is:

```
var emailMsg = `Name: ${name}\nEmail: ${email}\n\nMessage:\n${msg}`;

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: process.env.GMAIL_ACC,
        clientId: process.env.GMAIL_CLIENTID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GMAIL_CLIENTSECRET,
        refreshToken: process.env.GMAIL_RFRESHTOKEN,
        accessToken: process.env.GMAIL_ACCESSTOKEN
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.GMAIL_ACC,
    to: process.env.GMAIL_ACC,
    subject: `Contact Form - ${name}`,
    text: emailMsg
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,
    function(mailErr, mailRes) {
        if(mailErr) {
            //Mail was unable to send
            sendResponse(418, false, [{'email': 'Server was unable to send email.'}]);
            console.log('Mail Error:\n ', mailErr);
        } else {
            //Everything worked correctly. (As far as responses go)
            sendResponse(200, true);
        }
    }
);
```

Things I have tried:
 - Allowing less secure apps (Doesn't seem to have any affect)
 - Disabling AntiVirus (This was originally a problem for something unrelated)
 - Creating a new app and set of tokens (This has had 0 affect)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process.env.GMAIL_RFRESHTOKEN` - Should this be `GMAIL_REFRESH_TOKEN`? Looking through the source code of the library, it would appear this error would be thrown *directly* from the GMail API, as the library never constructs this error itself. This would support the theory that the refresh token is undefined/null.

Comment: Yep, thanks! Seems I didn't copy and paste quite as much as I thought I did.

Comment: Can I get help for mail using **zoho service**  & **access_token**? @ZoëClarno

Answer (score 5):

The problem is because the access token going to expire in 3600 seconds. You have to generate a new one using your refresh token. See this good article which can help you to solve your problem: https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1

Comment: Thank you saved my day! great article (went through 3 until found your comment and it is working)

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same using your email address and password. Here's how it's used:

```js
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL, // your email address
        pass: process.env.PASS, // your email password
      },
    });

    const mailOptions = {
      from: `"Auth Admin" <${process.env.EMAIL}>`,
      to: email,
      subject: "Account Verification: NodeJS Auth System",
      generateTextFromHTML: true,
      html: output,
    };
```

Comment: Not any more. Gmail API doesn't support Less Secure Apps anymore.