# GSuite Error: Can't create new access token for user - OAuth2 Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, smtp, gmail, nodemailer, google-workspace

I'm trying to send emails through gmail from nodejs but I keep running into this error.

```
Error: Can't create new access token for user
  at XOAuth2.generateToken(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js: 184: 33)
  at XOAuth2.getToken(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\xoauth2\index.js: 123: 18)
  at SMTPConnection._handleXOauth2Token(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 1697: 27)
  at SMTPConnection.login(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 540: 22)
  at c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - transport\index.js: 374: 32
  at SMTPConnection.<anonymous>(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 215: 17)
  at Object.onceWrapper(events.js: 420: 28)
  at SMTPConnection.emit(events.js: 314: 20)
  at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 1313: 14)
  at SMTPConnection._processResponse(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 942: 20)
  at SMTPConnection._onData(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 749: 14)
  at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData(c: \apps\node\myapp\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp - connection\index.js: 195: 44)
  at TLSSocket.emit(events.js: 314: 20)
  at addChunk(_stream_readable.js: 304: 12)
  at readableAddChunk(_stream_readable.js: 280: 9)
  at TLSSocket.Readable.push(_stream_readable.js: 219: 10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
    command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2'
}
```

I have set up my G Suite account, created a service account and enabled the Gmail API for that project. I have also enabled G-Suite domain wide delegation for the service account and added the client ID and the proper scope to my G Suite account.

I downloaded my credentials file and renamed it to use `.js` so I could import it as an ES module.

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import * as key from "../credentials.js";

const SENDER_EMAIL = "support@domain.com";
const RECEIVER_EMAIL = "customer@gmail.com";

async function start() {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",
      user: SENDER_EMAIL,
      serviceClient: key.client_id,
      privateKey: key.private_key,
    },
  });

  try {
    await transporter.verify();
    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: SENDER_EMAIL,
      to: RECEIVER_EMAIL,
      subject: "Hello Humans",
      text: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

export default start;
```

Now, calling `start()` errors out with the above message. I can't figure it out. Help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to use nodemailer to send emails using gmail and am receiving the error: "Can't create new access token for user"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665349/trying-to-use-nodemailer-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-am-receiving-the-error)

Comment: Do you encounter the same problem if you hardcode the values for  `serviceClient` and `privateKey`?

Comment: Interestingly, no I do not. When I hard code those values the error disappears.

Comment: Seems then that the error is related to renaming your credentials / the way you retrieve them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you solved your issue 11 months ago but, for those who find this, I had the same issue and found the answer [here](https://dev.to/i_maka/google-cloud-functions-sending-emails-using-gmail-smtp-and-nodemailer-1lij). I believe this might be your case specially because you mentioned that hardcoding the value does work.

Apparently, the `\n` in the private key brings some issues when used this way. In my case, I'm taking the private key value from [Firebase runtime config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), and following suggestions in that link I ended up with a `replace(/\\n/g, '\n')` on the key:

```js
const nodemailerTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: env.nodemailer.host,
  port: 465,
  secure: true, // true for TLS 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: env.nodemailer.user,
    serviceClient: env.nodemailer.clientid,
    privateKey: env.nodemailer.privatekey.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),  // <=== HERE
    accessUrl: env.nodemailer.tokenuri, // <== HERE
  },
});
```

which does work. I'm using `"host": "smtp-relay.gmail.com"` but it's the same for your `smtp.gmail.com` case.

Also consider the `accessUrl` (the `token_uri` as taken from credentials.json):

```
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
```

which is not the same as the default used by nodemailer (`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`). IDK if that matters.